# Updating boost libraries without affecting existing binaries

Tags: unix, boost, shared-libraries, dependency-management

I would like to do some development for which I need boost. (I'm using Fedora 19). The installation on the boost site seems straightforward and I'm pretty much ready. However, I found that I already have some shared boost libraries but I don't have any headers. Furthermore, I have a lot of installed software that uses the shared libs. For example

```
ldd /usr/bin/checkpto
```

produces

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff7b115000)
    libhuginbase.so.0.0 => /usr/lib64/hugin/libhuginbase.so.0.0 (0x0000003a92c00000)
    libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0 => /lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x0000003a98200000)
    libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0 => /lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x0000003a98600000)
    ...
```

Now I want to do a full boost install, but what will happen to all the binaries I have that already depend on the existing boost libraries? Will I have to maintain two sets? As you might guess from the ldd output, there are no symlinks to those libraries. They are all files. Could yum resolve the dependencies and update the binaries that depend on them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you need a different version of the boost library than that available in the Fedora repository.

If you do not need a different version, you can simply install all the boost library packages from the Fedora repository including the `...-devel` packages which provide the library headers.

If you do a different version, you will have to obtain the boost source distribution, build it and install it yourself. You just need to make sure that you DO NOT install it in the default system locations (e.g. /usr/include, /usr/lib, /usr/lib64). That way, your version can live side by side with the Fedora versions in perfect harmony.